# Where are the log files located in Windows?

Tags: windows, python, logging

I've got a program written in Python that writes to `stderr` and `stdout`. I invoke it using `pythonw`, that means it runs *without* a command line.

Does Windows save those log files and if yes, where?

(I know I can redirect them in python or using the command line, but are they stored automatically?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your program is called from a Command Prompt, stderr and stdout are by default directed to the console.

If you want to save them to a file, you must redirect the output.

> STDOUT:
>
> ```
> c:\path\program.exe >c:\temp\stdout.log
> ```
>
> STDERR:
>
> ```
> c:\path\program.exe 2>c:\temp\stderr.log
> ```
>
> STDOUT and STDERR in different files
>
> ```
> c:\path\program.exe >c:\temp\stdout.log 2>c:\temp\stderr.log
> ```
>
> STDOUT and STDERR in the same file
>
> ```
> c:\path\program.exe >c:\temp\stdout.log 2>&1
> ```

If you want to add to an existing log file instead of overwriting the content, use ">>" instead of ">". If the logfile does not exist, it will be create in both cases.

Edit:
You edited your question with more details after my initial answer.
So the new answer would be: no, they are not stored automatically. You must explicitly redirect the output streams to a file if you want to.

Comment: Your answer is better. +1

Comment: DOS died long ago. "Command Prompt" aka `cmd.exe` is a native Win32 program.